# Prevent ctrl-B from setting bold font while working with md files with the Markdown All in One extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, when you are working with a markdown file with the "Markdown All in One" extension active, `ctrl-B` sets the selected text to bold by surrounding it with `**`

The problem is that I use the `ctrl-B` keyboard shortcut all the time to show/hide the side bar.

Is there any way to disable that emboldening shortcut (or define an alternative one) when working with Markdown files, and to use it for hiding the side bar?

edit: the problem was that I had the 'Markdown All in One' installed

Comment: You are right, sorry, it was the 'Markdown All in One', I forgot I had it installed

Comment: So you don't rely on that extension? If so, would you accept an answer saying to uninstall it? Either way, please [edit] your question to say that you have that extension installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can currently be done without uninstalling / deactivating your "Markdown All in One" extension. If you look at the list of keybinding actions it offers (see those that start with `markdown.extension.editor.toggle`), there are ones for toggling code spans, blocks, math, lists, but none for toggling bold and italics, which I find strange. No dice either searching for suggestions in the keybindings.json with "markdown.extensionbold".

So either I'm missing something, or you need to [make a feature-request on their GitHub](https://github.com/yzhang-gh/vscode-markdown/issues).

As a last resort to get a fix right now, you could just remap your toggle-side-bar keybinding to something else.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.